# Notification não aparece no "Assisant" no Firebase

Tags: firebase

[image: Não aparece a opção notification para aplicar ao projeto o que devo fazer?(sou novo no android studio)]

Não aparece a opção notification para aplicar ao projeto. O que devo fazer? (sou novo no android studio)

Answer (score 0):

O Firebase Notifications funciona através do Cloud Messaging que você pode encontrar no Firebase Assistant:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontre mais detalhes na [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message?hl=pt-br#send_messages_to_foregrounded_apps).